Unable to Add New People to Roles in Meta Live App
enter image description hereI am currently experiencing an issue with my Meta Live app where I am unable to see the "Add People" tab under the Roles section.
Steps I have taken so far:
Logged in with my main Facebook account (which originally created the Meta app).
Attempted to use another admin account to add new people.
Despite these attempts, the "Add People" tab is still not visible.
For additional context, my main Facebook account, which created the Meta app, is currently restricted from ads management. Could this restriction be affecting my ability to add new people to roles in my app?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
